# Makefile error 1, -std=c++11 -c

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm writing a program that uses nullpointers in c++ and I'm getting the error

```
g++ -g -std=c++11-c main.cpp
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11-c’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I'm not sure what's going on and I've searched but the solutions don't appear like they would apply.

```
all: Lab03


Lab03: main.o Box.o StackOfBoxes.o
    g++ -g -std=c++11 main.o Box.o StackOfBoxes.o -o Lab03

main.o: main.cpp StackOfBoxes.h
    g++ -g -std=c++11-c main.cpp

Box.o: Box.cpp Box.h
    g++ -g -std=c++11 Box.cpp

StackOfBoxes.o: StackOfBoxes.cpp StackOfBoxes.h
    g++ -g -std=c++11 StackOfBoxes.cpp

clean:
    rm  *o Lab03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
-std=c++11 -c
          ^
```

Comment: See source for failed joke.

Answer (score 0):

You literally just have a typo in your makefile, in the rule for `main.o`. Add a space before the `-c`.

Comment: I hate myself for missing that. Thanks!